# Indent using spaces with phpfmt sublime plugin

Tags: php, sublimetext3, spaces

I'm using phpfmt on my sublime 3 setup but after formatting my spaces indentation is automatically converted in tabs.

I've tried to setup my user conf like this, but it's not working at all:

```
{
  "format_on_save": true,
  "php_bin": "/usr/local/opt/php70/bin/php",
  "readini": false,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
  "version": 1
}
```

How can I set the opposite behaviour? Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using command palette, choose "phpfmt: indentation with spaces"

Comment: Why should i? I want to use tabs. Why do i have to use spaces?